# Is it possible to authenticate into salesforce using python and simple-salesforce library using a more secure method than a security token?

Tags: python, authentication, salesforce

I have some scripts with python and simple-salesforce and I have read on medium that there is a more secure way to authenticate where you some how plug into Salesforce CLI to get an instance url and a temporary security token, which you can feed through to an instance of Salesforce() before running simple-salesforce functions on the resulting object. https://python.plainenglish.io/utilize-sfdx-to-login-and-automate-salesforce-using-python-b5baa5eff704

My programming skills aren't very advanced, so I might be a bit confused on some of this. Heres the code I came up with, which produces a key error with "result".

```
import subprocess
import json
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce


sfdx_cmd = subprocess.Popen('sfdx force:org:display --targetusername myself@mycompany.org --json',shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
sfdx_info = json.loads(sfdx_cmd.communicate()[0])

access_token = sfdx_info['result']['accessToken']
instance_url = sfdx_info['result']['instanceUrl']


sf = Salesforce(instance_url=instance_url,session_id=access_token)
print(sf.query_all("select id from Contact limit 1"))
```

The resulting output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/justinharford/My Drive/Documents/Python/SF Tools/safe_auth.py", line 7, in 
access_token = sfdx_info['result']['accessToken']
KeyError: 'result'